# Chef "waiting for remote response before bootstrap" indefinitely

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, chef

**Problem:**  My client does not respond to my bootstrap command, no error is reported.

**Expected Outcome:**  I would expect the client to respond within a few seconds of running `knife bootstrap`.

My command from workstation: `knife bootstrap windows winrm 192.168.100.36 -x <my_domain>\\<my_user> -p 5985`

**Configurations I have executed on client:**
On the client:

```
winrm quickconfig -q 
winrm set winrm/config/winrs '@{MaxMemoryPerShellMB="300"}'
winrm set winrm/config '@{MaxTimeoutms="1800000"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service '@{AllowUnencrypted="true"}'
winrm set winrm/config/service/auth '@{Basic="true"}'
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5985" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5985 action=allow 
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="WinRM 5986" protocol=TCP dir=in localport=5986 action=allow 
net stop winrm 
net start winrm
```

**Troubleshooting steps completed:**

- I can telnet to client on port 5985 but not 5986.
- I can run `invoke-command` from workstation to client successfully.
- Firewall on client has been completely disabled (for testing).

Comment: Also encountered this problem, my work around is to press the enter key.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has to do with the credentials you're using.  Are you able to execute:

```
knife winrm 'NODENAME' 'ipconfig' -m -x DOMAIN\\USER
```

I'm betting you recieve:

```
ERROR: Failed to authenticate to ["NODENAME"] as DOMAIN\\USER
```

I've seen this error when a server is in a trust relationship with another domain and it's the other domain credentials that need to be used (or a local admin user account).

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**: Press the enter key

**Solution**: Could be that powershell is pausing the output. Uncheck these options in powershell

[image]

See: [Sometimes PowerShell stops sending output until I press enter](https://serverfault.com/q/204150).